# Merge two active record results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a slight problem.

Basically, I'm looking to get a list of items from a table that I have a model for ordered by date but items with a date in the last hour (`DateTime.now-30.minutes..DateTime.now+30.minutes`) should appear at the top of the results.

I need to be able to use `where` and other active record methods on the result so `+` is out of the question.

At the moment I'm getting two results: 1 with all the records and 1 with the records within the timeframe and then using `merge` but that then wipes out the 1st array.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: Can you please give some code of your own with your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
@latest = Model1.where...
@all = Model1.all

@merged = @latest | @all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE created_at 
WHEN > 1.hour.ago THEN 1
ELSE 2, created_at
```

in case of ActiveRecord scope it will be the following:

```
order("CASE WHEN created_at>'#{1.hour.ago.to_date}' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, created_at")
```

So you can use the one query instead of two. and you don't need merge.

I can give you more detailed example if you show your model

Answer (score 0):

What about `Model.order("date_column DESC")` ?

There are several ways to implement this. Usually you define a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) for simple and a finder-method for more complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you would use a `UNION` to merge two queries. Rails does not support UNION out of the box, but the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tlowrimore/5162327) should do the trick. I've tried this once and it worked, not sure if it suits your needs though.